# Where do I put image for appcelerator ios?

Tags: ios, appcelerator

I'm porting my android app over to ios, using appcelerator titanium.

If i define an image for use in a view or whatever like so

```
backgroundImage : "/images/blueButton.png",
```

What is the file location that i would put blueButton.png?
Is it `/resources/iphone`, `/resources/images`, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

According to Malcolm Hollingsworth in [this answer on the archived Appcelerator forum](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/149743/images-in-android#answer-258910):

> Device specific images should be placed inside the **android** folder of
>   android specific images and **iphone** for iOS images (iPhone, iPod and
>   iPad).
>
> If you are creating an app that support both main platforms and some
>   image are the same no matter the device (think photos) then you can
>   and should create a folder outside the device folders.

With this example:

> Now in a cross platform app supporting all image densities (or at
>   least the main ones - your folders would look like this with the
>   images inside;
>
> ```
> /resources/
> /resources/android/
> /resources/android/images/res-ldpi/test1.png
> /resources/android/images/res-mdpi/test1.png
> /resources/android/images/res-hdpi/test1.png
> /resources/android/images/res-xhdpi/test1.png
> /resources/iphone/
> /resources/iphone/images/test1.png
> /resources/iphone/images/test1@2x.png
> ```
>
> With these two being
>
> ```
> /resources/iphone/images/test1.png = non-retina
> /resources/iphone/images/test1@2x.png = retina
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Then your code would be;
>
> ```
> var myImageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
> height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
> image : '/images/test1.png',
> width: Ti.UI.SIZE });
> ```

Hat tip to Malcolm Hollingsworth.

Answer (score 1):

For **iOS** Places images in **"/resources/images"** path and that should work fine. for iOS non-retina display image name in resource folder should be normal (in our example below it will be myImage.png), for retina display image name in resource folder should be myImage@2x.png with double size than non-retina image.

For **Android** Place images in device specific folder in **"resources/android/images/"** path and that should work fine.

```
var myImage = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
height : Titanium.UI.SIZE,
width : Titanium.UI.SIZE,
image : "/images/myImage.png"
});
```

**this code will work fine for both android and iOS.**

**Note :** in iOS you can directly place images in iPhone folder and use image : "myImage.png" as parameter in createImageView, but it won't work in android. so it's better to use above folder structure where same images are used in iOS and android both.
you can places images that are device specific directly in iPhone folder as they will never be used in android devices.